# Diebold-Mariano test for comparing multivariate models

Tags: regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing, inference, diebold-mariano-test

I want to know if there exists a Diebold-Mariano test version for comparing the accuracy of predictions between multivariate statistics models. For example, compare a VAR model and multivariate GARCH predictions.

Comment: Please don’t [cross-post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/104424/73930) on multiple Stacks.

Comment: I think I have seen an extension of the Diebold-Mariano test to multiple dependent variables somewhere. Try searching on Google Scholar.

Comment: One easy (albeit not necessarily satisfactory) strategy could be to reduce the loss difference needed for DM to a univariate quantity again, e.g., by simply summing up the squared prediction errors from each equation of the VAR. Some standardization could then be helpful to get the errors on the same scale.